# tabControls remove space and arrow button on the right side

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Iam using visual studio 2015 and winforms, i want to use tabControl with four tabPages. I have set tabControl1.SizeMode to

```
TabSizeMode.Fixed
```

And i have set tabControl1.ItemSize with this value

```
new Size(tabControl1.Width / 4, 50)
```

But when i compile, tabControl give me like i set five tabPages, there is a space on the right side, and arrow button.
How to remove that space and arrow button?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove that, just change `tabControl1.Width / 4` to `tabControl1.Width / 4 - 1`.

You can do like this:

```
tabControl1.ItemSize = new Size(tabControl1.Width / 4 - 1, 50)
```

Comment: Okay thank you, i have search with many keywords and almost give up.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is to let the `TabControl` auto-resize, thus do NOT use any fixed `width` properties. To remove the horizontal extra space, check for the `margin` settings and, upon necessity, set them to 0. For more details, you can refer to this: [How to get a TabControl to resize with other members inside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390628/how-to-get-a-tabcontrol-to-resize-with-other-members-inside-of-it)

Hope this will help.

Comment: problem solved by @Sakura's solution, but thank you for your information

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Best regards,